# Google BigQuery Import csv Using Console - Use first row as header

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a csv file with 1 column which I want to import into my big query environment. When using the Console to import data - always take my first row as a data row rather than a column name. Is there a way in the console to always ensure the first row is always the column name

E.g.

| Tk Number |
| --- |
| Tk - 0001 |
| Tk - 0002 |

Answer (score 3):

In CSV format, if the first row is string and others are integers, then it automatically takes the first row as header name, if you have checked the auto-detect schema option while creating the table.

But since you have strings in header as well as body, you will need to give the schema manually while creating the table in BigQuery. And in advanced options you can specify the number of rows to be skipped under 'header rows to skip' option.
[image: Creating a table][image: Skipping header row]